# Does Node.js fs.readFile() work as PHP's file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, node.js, fs

I have the following scripts that read and print an image as string:

PHP:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/small.png");
```

Node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/small.png', 'utf8');
console.log(file)
```

But there's a little bit difference between the strings output by 2 scripts. I tried the same thing with the following Go code and the outputs is identical to PHP's:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/small.png")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    content := string(buf)
    fmt.Println(content)
}
```

So, anybody got an idea why does fs.readFile() behave differently?

Answer (score 3):

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/small.png', 'binary');
console.log(file)
```

references:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L432

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the 2 scripts still output different bytes..

Answer (score 0):

[Garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). If you tell Node that your binary picture file is a plain text file encoded as UTF-8, it's no wonder you get unexpected results.

On the other side, your PHP code just prints the exact bytes read.